# AWS Lightsail - How to decide whether I need to upgrade the plan or use load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, amazon-lightsail

As the application grows, there will be a need to handle massive traffic. However, my question is, how should I decide to either upgrade the plan or use a load balancer?

Comment: Please edit your question to tell us more about your application and the workload. Is it a web app? Does it use a database? Is it currently running on a single instance (including database)? Can it run on multiple instances in parallel? More information, please!

Answer (score 2):

Only you will be able to determine when to upgrade your services.

You should monitor your instances to find any processing bottlenecks, which are typically either CPU, RAM, network throughput or disk access. If one of these factors shows limits, upgrade accordingly.

A common technique is to **simulate traffic** on a test system to determine where bottlenecks might lie and to identify when to scale-up. However, this might be overkill for your existing system.

If you decide to scale-out to multiple instances (if your application permits this), then you would also need a Load Balancer to distribute the traffic across the instances. If you are using a database, it would also require the database to be *external* to those instances so that it has shared access to all instances.